# sql - select all records having a field set or null

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select

I have a stored procedure, in which I want to select all the records of a table T having the user_id field equal to a parameter p_user_id:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE user_id = p_user_id;
```

but if the parameter is NULL (or zero if you prefer) I want all the records. 
That is, I can't think of the CASE in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE user_id = p_user_id
OR p_user_id is null
OR p_user_id = 0
```

Should work.

Here the clause `user_id = p_user_id` will equate to UNKNOWN if p_user_id is null which in *most* databases will have the result of not matching any rows ([sybase](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/7285;pt=6605/%2a) is an exception).

Comment: "the clause user_id = p_user_id will always be false if p_user_id is null" -- no, it should be UNKNOWN and the distinction is crucial. If it was FALSE then every `CHECK` constraints would reject the `NULL` value unless explicitly handled.

Comment: ...this is stated clearly in the link you yourself posted: "Only columns that return a value of TRUE are selected or result in the specified action; those that return FALSE or UNKNOWN do not... In general, the result of comparing null values is UNKNOWN, since it is impossible to determine whether NULL is equal (or not equal) to a given value or to another NULL."

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * FROM T WHERE user_id = p_user_id or p_user_id is null or p_user_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM T WHERE user_id = @p_user_id  OR  @p_user_id IS NULL`

The OR clause is true when the parameter is NULL (NULL IS NULL == TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
IF p_user_id IS NULL
    (SELECT * FROM T);
ELSE
    (SELECT * FROM T WHERE user_id = p_user_id)
```